# Open multiple hyperlinks in one window using Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to open several Hyperlinks in multiple tabs from excel in one window:

```
Sub Open_Hyperlinks()
Range("C10:C17").Select
Dim hl as Hyperlink
On Error resume next
for Each hl in selection.Hyperlinks
hl.Follow
Next hl
End Sub
```

But I would like to include a specific instruction to open the hyperlinks using Internet Explorer and not the default browser setup in my terminal due to the fact that for administrator permissions I'm not able to change it.

Do you know how to include that instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by calling Internet Explorer directly:
`Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -url  " & hl. Address ,vbMaximizedFocus)`

Comment: I use the instruction in the following way:  <br>   Sub Open_Hyperlinks()
_Range("C10:C17").Select
Dim hl as Hyperlink <br> Call Shell("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -url  " & hl. Address ,vbMaximizedFocus)
On Error resume next
for Each hl in selection.Hyperlinks
hl.Follow
Next hl
End Sub_  <br>  but appears the error message: <br>  Run-time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set, do you know what does that mean?

Comment: You need to put the `call` in your `for` loop,  remove the `hl.Follow` and replace by the line I mentioned.